# What are the default heights of CupertinoTabBar and CupertinoSliverNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm trying to set widgets sizes according to screen height. For example i have 3 widgets inside my body, the first and second one should be 20% from whole screen size, the third one - the rest.

The problem is that i have CupertinoSliverNavigatoinBar and CupertinoTabBar, so i can't calculate height of my third widget.

I'm trying to implement [this](https://github.com/dancamdev/effectively_scale_UI_according_to_different_screen_sizes) thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, CupertinoTabBar height is `50.0`. To verify this you can check the source code of CupertinoTabBar and there is constant which called `_kTabBarHeight`. 
But for your particular problem I think you should use `Expanded` widget with `flex` property.